# Stuck on a node.js and jquery communication bug.

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Here's my problem. Im working on displaying and manipulating a simple mysql database on a node.js application. I'm also using jquery and bootstrap. I know that the two packages are successfully referenced in my main.handlebars. My application home page loads appropriately but I'm using a render and renderTable function in my app.js file to display the tables that I have received from the call to my database. I have confirmed that I am getting data back from the database. I receive no errors in my developer tools and when I bypass app.js and render the tables by making app.get requests I receive the correct data.

My problem is that something is preventing the rendering of my tables when I load my home page. It was my understanding that when I set the `$(document).ready(function()` the function would execute when the page is loaded.

My assumption is that something is not properly communicating in my app.js file and preventing the render functions from executing. I am a novice with node.js so im likely overlooking something very simple but I am not sure what it is.

app.js render functions

```
var renderTable = function(url, selector) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $(selector).html('');
      $(selector).append('<h3>' + selector.substring(1) + '</h3>' + jsonToTable(data, selector.substring(1)));
      $(selector).append(composeForm(selector, getKeys(data.results[0])));
      $(selector + ' .save').on('click', submitEntry);
      $(selector + ' .delete').on('click', deleteEntry);
    }
  });
};
var render = function() {
   console.log(Im Here!);
   renderTable('/artists', '#artists');
   renderTable('/country', '#country');
   renderTable('/city', '#city');
   renderTable('/medium', '#medium');
   renderTable('/artists_medium', '#artists_medium');
   renderTable('/artists_residence', '#artists_residence');
   $('.search').on('click', searchChar);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("App.js is reached.");
  render();
});
```

server.js requests

```
var selectTableData = function(res, table) {
  var ctx = {};
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM ' + table, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    ctx.results = rows;
    res.send(ctx);
  });
};

app.get('/artists', function(req, res) {
  selectTableData(res, 'artists');
});

app.get('/country', function(req, res) {
  selectTableData(res, 'country');
});

app.get('/city', function(req, res) {
  selectTableData(res, 'city');
});

app.get('/medium', function(req, res) {
  selectTableData(res, 'medium');
});

app.get('/artists_medium', function(req, res) {
  selectTableData(res, 'artists_medium');
});

app.get('/artists_residence', function(req, res) {
  selectTableData(res, 'artists_residence');
});
```

Theses are of course snippets of a larger project.

Comment: Open the developer toolbar, check the network tab, look at the request the actually send and at the response you got back from the server.

Comment: There is no meaningful information that I can see in the requests and response and also no errors. Only 304 status code for app.js and a response that is just the duplicate file. I have a search button also in the page and when I select that it is supposed to refresh the page with search results and again no rendering is made to the page.

Comment: Maybe try to find something meaningful, request cant be done without... request. So if you have nothing in console and network tab then you probably debugging wrong page.

Comment: right my, home page loads and I get my home.handlebars view but It was my assumption that the `$(document).ready(function()` would handle the rendering of my tables.